# Unexpected usage of @Select in NGXS docs

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngxs

At NGXS docs for [action dispatching](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/store#dispatching-actions), there's a passage mentioning that getting the state after an add operation could be done using `@Select`.

```
@Component({ ... })
export class ZooComponent {
  @Select(state => state.animals) animals$: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  addAnimal(name: string) {
    this.store.dispatch(new AddAnimal(name)).pipe(withLatestFrom(this.animals$))
      .subscribe(([_, animals]) => { this.form.reset(); });
  }
}
```

Keeping in mind that I'm extremely new to the Redux pattern, I'm scrutinizing the docs and following it section by section in the suggested order. There's no aforementioned `@Select` (except in an image) and I feel that I missed something. I can look up the decorator in other places but I suspect that I missed something as it pops up with no prior description.

Should the mentioning of the `@Select` decorator be seen as a side-thing at this point? A bit clumsy amended info, so to speak? Or is it a fundamental point, which I'm missing?

I also noticed that the dispatching is followed by a pipe but with one argument only. And those two unexpected observation make me uncertain. it seems like the docs are a bit sloppy here but I do fear that they aren't and that it's me who misses the point.

And at my current competence level I have no way to determine that.

Comment: It's one of the core reasons why you would use Ngxs. The `@Select()` and `@Selector()` work together. https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select

Comment: @Reactgular I see. What I reacted on was that the concept of selector wasn't introduced firstly. It somehow gets injected in a indirect way and it got me unsure if I missed something prior to the linked section or if they actually introduce the selector ninja style while discussing the store. I always worry that I'm too dumb to grasp a concept so every deviation is a hint that I might be right in my fear.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana the `@Select` is just a syntactic sugar over `store.select`. Austin (our previous lead) decided to leave only super simple examples there for demonstrating purposes.

Comment: @overthesanity I take you're part of the contributing population on that project. Firstly - thank you for doing adaptations the Angular way. Secondly - you might want to post your comment as an answer to be accepted. Also, do you have something to share in the regarding the pipe with only a single argument (that also triggered my attention)?

Comment: I don't think my comment is a propper answer, haha :D Didn't fully understand your third question. Probably lost in translation as I'm not a native speaker :D

Comment: @overthesanity The question is whether `pipe(...)` is required there as the usual way to apply the function `pipe(x,y,z)` is with multiple operators to be pipe'd not a single one. I was wondering if the example had multiple operators as arguments and then got sloppily edited. I'm not entirely sure, though.

Comment: I do not understand this part > `The question is whether pipe(...) is required there as the usual way to apply the function pipe(x,y,z) is with multiple operators to be pipe'd not a single one`, sorry. I guess it's better to ask @Reactgular as he's a native speaker.

Comment: `pipe(..)` is ok either way, with one or more operators in there. If you're on rxjs v6 then you'll need to use `pipe` rather than the legacy dot chaining operators you may have used in previous versions.   And yes, as the others have said `@Select` gives you an `Observable` stream of a slice of the state store.